# Can't solidify login using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

been recoding my site using code igniter. I am having some quirks with my seemingly sensical scripts.

*please note that I am aware of not encrypting passwords but am just clear texting until I can get signed in and will implement as step 2*

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@gmail.com && password = Password LIMIT 1' at line 1
>
> SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = mr-t@gmail.com && password =
>   Password LIMIT 1

[HERE](https://gist.github.com/7d59e7295b167883bbd2) is my code along with an explanation of my problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow is really intended more for specific coding problems rather than general code reviews.  The other issue is that if that link is ever down, or the content changes, then this question really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have quotes around Password and Email on your select statement.

The following should work for your case:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('email'));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('password'));
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = "' . $email . '" && password = "' . $password . '" LIMIT 1');
```

Comment: Worked right away! I knew I was something minor and I was on the right path. THANKS!

Comment: This code doesn't use CodeIgniter to build the query. CodeIgniter will take care of escaping the values and building the queries for you, so it is more provider-agnostic (and less work). See my answer for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the single quotes with double quotes on your `$this->input->post()` sections.  I think you're escaping out the variables.

Answer (score 0):

In CI, you're supposed to do it this way:

```
$this->db->select("id");
$this->db->from("users");
$this->db->where("email", $this->input->post('email'));
$this->db->where("password", $this->input->post('password'));
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->query();
```